# Json is stored as = instead of : colon in postgres DB

Tags: java, json, spring, postgresql, hibernate

I have a Gradle spring-boot project. I want to store a json in postgres DB column(rules) and so defined the type of column as TEXT.
When I am hitting the save endpoint via postman I am sending this data

```
{
  "rules": {"key": "97773e0b-3639-4af5-9585-93bc176715c0", "fieldName": "esn", "operator": "eq", "operands": ["599320"]},
  "name": "user",
  "sso": "502622018",
  "ruleMatching": "ALL"
}
```

But when I hit the GET endpoint I am getting this response which is not a json but a kind of string where : are converted to = and the quotes are not stored.

```
{
    "id": 9,
    "name": "user",
    "ruleMatching": "ALL",
    "sso": "502622018",
    "rules": "{key=97773e0b-3639-4af5-9585-93bc176715c0, fieldName=esn, operator=eq, operands=[599320]}"
}
```

How do I save the `rules` as a proper json in DB as TEXT type ? Any suggestion?

Here is the Entity definition and the dto definition

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@Entity
@Getter @Setter @AllArgsConstructor @NoArgsConstructor
@Builder(toBuilder=true)
@Table(name="saved_filters")
@TypeDef(
        name = "jsonb",
        typeClass = JsonBinaryType.class
    )
public class SavedFilter implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="id")
    private int id;

    @Column(name="name")
    private String name;

  
    @Column(name="rule_matching")
    private String ruleMatching;
    
    
    @Column(name="rules", columnDefinition= "TEXT")
    private String rules;

    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_sso")
    private User user;
```

----DTO--

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@Data
@Getter @Setter @AllArgsConstructor @NoArgsConstructor
@Builder(toBuilder=true)
public class SavedFilterDto implements Serializable {

    private int id;

    private String name;
    
    @JsonProperty("rules")
    private Object rules;
    
    private String ruleMatching;

    private String sso;      
    
}
```

---

After changing the column to jsonb, I am getting the following error

```
RemoteUserContext --> ef227333-4629-4571-bf2f-210c64902eea
2021-03-23 23:42:23 [http-nio-9090-exec-1] DEBUG c.g.d.o.m.c.FilterController.createSavedFilter - Start...SavedFilterDto(id=0, name=user, rules={key=97773e0b-3639-4af5-9585-93bc176715c0, fieldName=esn, operator=eq, operands=[599320]}, ruleMatching=ALL, sso=502622018)
Hibernate: select user0_.sso as sso1_35_0_, user0_.email as email2_35_0_, user0_.first_name as first_na3_35_0_, user0_.hidden as hidden4_35_0_, user0_.last_name as last_nam5_35_0_, user0_.updated_at as updated_6_35_0_, user0_.user_id as user_id7_35_0_ from user_info user0_ where user0_.sso=?
Hibernate: insert into saved_filters (name, rule_matching, rules, user_sso) values (?, ?, ?, ?)
2021-03-23 23:42:24 [http-nio-9090-exec-1] ERROR c.g.d.o.m.e.GenericExceptionHandler.handleException - Application error
org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('k' (code 107)): was expecting double-quote to start field name
 at [Source: (String)"{key=97773e0b-3639-4af5-9585-93bc176715c0, fieldName=esn, operator=eq, operands=[599320]}"; line: 1, column: 3]; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('k' (code 107)): was expecting double-quote to start field name
 at [Source: (String)"{key=97773e0b-3639-4af5-9585-93bc176715c0, fieldName=esn, operator=eq, operands=[599320]}"; line: 1, column: 3]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:351) ~[spring-orm-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:253) ~[spring-orm-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
```

If I change the private Object rules; in DTO to private String rules;..I am getting the following error :

```
2021-03-24 11:12:05 [http-nio-9090-exec-10] WARN  o.s.w.s.m.m.a.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver.logException - Resolved [org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize instance of `java.lang.String` out of START_OBJECT token; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize instance of `java.lang.String` out of START_OBJECT token
 at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 2, column: 12] (through reference chain: com.ge.digital.oa.moa.dto.SavedFilterDto["rules"])]
```

Comment: Your `rules` property is of type `String`.  If you want the value of that `String` to replace `=` with some other character (like `:`) you would have to write something that will take the JSON object `{"key": "97773e0b-3639-4af5-9585-93bc176715c0", "fieldName": "esn", "operator": "eq", "operands": ["599320"]}` and turn it into a `String` that satisfies your requirement.  There is nothing in the framework that would assume you want that.

Comment: I believe you have two options - (1) Convert `rules` to a `jsonb` datatype (2) Keep `rules` as `text` data type and use ObjectMapper to marshal/unmarshal programmatically

Comment: I have converted the column to jsonb but when I try to insert..I am getting the above error mentioned in the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to save the jsonb object with the help of 2 things -

1. Used a third-party library for Hibernate Types `implementation group: 'io.hypersistence', name: 'hypersistence-utils-hibernate-55', version: '3.0.1'`
2. Defined a POJO called Rules and used it in DTO and Entity class

public class Rules implements Serializable{

```
    private String key;
    private String fieldName;
    private String operator;
    private String eq;
    List<String> operands;

}
```

My Revised Entity class :

```
@Getter @Setter @AllArgsConstructor @NoArgsConstructor
@Builder(toBuilder=true)
@Table(name="saved_filters")
@TypeDef(
        name = "jsonb",
        typeClass = JsonBinaryType.class
    )
public class SavedFilter implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="id")
    private int id;

    @Column(name="name")
    private String name;

  
    @Column(name="rule_matching")
    private String ruleMatching;
    
    
    @Column(name="rules", columnDefinition= "jsonb")
    @Type(type = "jsonb")
    private Rules rules;

    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_sso")
    private User user;
```

And My Revised DTO class:

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@Data
@Getter @Setter @AllArgsConstructor @NoArgsConstructor
@Builder(toBuilder=true)
public class SavedFilterDto implements Serializable {

    private int id;

    private String name;
    
    @JsonProperty("rules")
    private Rules rules;
    
    private String ruleMatching;

    private String sso;      
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Updated answer**

> If saving in json format is not your prime concern, then you can
> follow this answer.

You can just do one thing to achieve it easily. Convert your key string with associated entities to a class and make it Embedded:

```
{"key": "97773e0b-3639-4af5-9585-93bc176715c0", "fieldName": "esn", "operator": "eq", "operands": ["599320"]}.
```

Create the embeddable class:

```
@Embeddable
Public class Rules
{
 private String key;
private String fieldName;
private String operator;
private String eq;
List<String> operands;
//getters and setters
}
```

Now in your `SaveFilter` class, add the Rules entity with embedded annotation:

```
 @Embedded
 @Column(name="rules")
 private Rules rules;
```

This will save your full object like a different column for each entity of the embedded object.

Comment: But I dont have any table named Rules

Comment: : [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: com.ge.digital.oa.moa.domain.Rules, at table: saved_filters, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(rules)]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapa

Comment: please check my answer again. Sorry for the last update. If saving in json is not your prime concern, then you can follow this approach, otherwise, you have add new table for rules and associate it with the parent one.

Comment: UI sends a json and expects a json response in GET..so need to store the json in DB